# How to find the column index of the value of a given row in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform something relatively simple in numpy:

- If there is a one in the row, return the index of the column containing the one +1.
- If there is zero or several one in the row return 0.

However I ended up with a pretty complex code:

```
predictions = np.array([[1,-1,-1,-1],[-1,1,1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,-1,-1]])

one_count = (predictions == 1).sum(1)
valid_rows_idx = np.where(one_count==1)

result = np.zeros(predictions.shape[0])
for idx in valid_rows_idx:
    result[idx] = np.where(predictions[idx,:]==1)[1] + 1
```

If I print `result`, the program prints 
`[ 1.  0.  4.  0.]` which is the desired result.

I was wondering if there is a simpler way of writing the last line using numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure is that better or not but you could try to use [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for that. Also you don't need to use for loop and `np.where` to get valid indices:

```
predictions = np.array([[1,-1,-1,-1],[-1,1,1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,-1,-1]])

idx = (predictions == 1).sum(1) == 1
result = np.zeros(predictions.shape[0])
result[idx] = (predictions[idx]==1).argmax(axis=1) + 1

In [55]: result
Out[55]: array([ 1.,  0.,  4.,  0.])
```

Or you could do all that stuff with one line using `np.where` and `argmax`:

```
predictions = np.array([[1,-1,-1,-1],[-1,1,1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,-1,-1]])

In [72]: np.where((predictions==1).sum(1)==1, (predictions==1).argmax(axis=1)+1, 0)
Out[72]: array([1, 0, 4, 0])
```